# \int not coming out right

Tags: math-operators

I am trying to write this:

[image: this]

Using

```
$$p_{\Theta | X} = \frac{f_{\Theta}(\theta) p_{X|\Theta}(x\,|\,\theta)}{\int f_{\Theta}(\theta ') p_{X|\Theta}(x\,|\,\theta ') \, d\theta '}$$
```

However, what I get is this instead:

[image: that]

The integral sign does not come out right.  Please help.

Comment: There are some intelligent people behind TeX and LaTeX. The behaviour you see is by design and what people usually want. Same for your other question.

Comment: You should also use `\mid` instead of `\,|\,`.

Comment: @Mico, thank you!  I have been wondering about the oddity of `\,|\,`.

Comment: This is identical to your previous question on `\sum`, again what you show is the standard layout, not wrong, although other layouts could be chosen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `\displaystyle` command in front of the `\int`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
f_{\Theta | X}(\theta | x) = \frac{f_{\Theta}(\theta) p_{X|\Theta}(x\,|\,\theta)}{\displaystyle\int f_{\Theta}(\theta ') p_{X|\Theta}(x\,|\,\theta ') \, d\theta '}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]
Also, it's not related at all, but [you should use `\[...\]` for display math mode, not `$$...$$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: Thank you!  That works.  I am using Auto-LaTeX on Google Docs.  Hence, `$$...$$`.

Comment: According to https://sites.google.com/site/autolatexequations/home, you can really use `\[ ... \]`, don't you? "Only converts equations within $$ or \\[ symbols, meaning you render only the equations you want to have rendered!"

Comment: @ivankokan, I didn't know that.  Thank you!

Comment: Note that the scope of that `\displaystyle` affects the entire denominator not just the integral sign.

Comment: I tried `\[P_X\]` and it did not work.  `$$P_X$$` works.  Any idea?

Comment: @J.Doe in a latex document (as posted in examples on this site) if in some non tex system you need `$$`  for it to recognise the math fragment that may be the case but it's essentially off topic here.

Comment: @J.Doe There is a drop-down selection in Auto-LaTeX Equations sidebar: Show Advanced Settings -> Select Delimiter Style. Although it seems that delimiters can be used exclusively, if you use both in your document, you can render both, e.g. select `$$ ... $$` and click Render Equations, then select `\[ ... \]` and click Render Equations again. When it comes to Derendering, I found this comment on XXX website a bit confusing: "Same Delimiter Derendering - When you derender new equations now, they will have the same delimiters they were rendered with ($$...$$ or \\[...\\]) ."

Comment: @J.Doe I suggest you contact Auto-LaTeX and propose improvements.

Comment: @ivankokan, I will try your solution.  I never got their Derendering working.

Comment: It works with `\[...\]` now.  Derendering too.  I guess previous attempts had complicated things it didn't like.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a pkg `nccmath`, here is a command `\medint` is useful

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}
\[
f_{\Theta | X}(\theta | x) = \frac{f_{\Theta}(\theta) p_{X|\Theta}(x\,|\,\theta)}%
{\medint\int f_{\Theta}(\theta ') p_{X|\Theta}(x\,|\,\theta ') \, d\theta '}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just only an addendum for the previous nice answers:

1. Using `empheq` to obtain the boxed formula with color;
2. Using `\mid` instead of `\,|\,` (as suggested by user @Mico) that it generates equal left and right blank space;
3. and...this [link](http://latexcolor.com/) to choose your preferite background color called http://latexcolor.com/.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{book}
    \usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
    \usepackage{empheq}
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.83, 0.83, 0.83}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{empheq}[box=\fcolorbox{lightgray}{lightgray}]{align}
    f_{\Theta \mid X}&=\frac{f_{\Theta}(\theta) p_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid\theta)}{\displaystyle \int f_{\Theta}(\theta') p_{X|\Theta}(x\mid\theta') \, d\theta'}
    \end{empheq}
    \end{document}
```

[image]